# Save Visio Document as HTML

Tags: python, com, visio, win32com

I'm trying to convert a lot of Visio files from `.vsd` to `.html`, but each file has a lot of pages, so I need to convert all pages to a single `.html` file.

Using the Python code below, I'm able to convert to PDF, but what I really need is HTML.  I noticed I can use `win32com.client.Dispatch("SaveAsWeb.VisSaveAsWeb")`, but how to use it?  Any ideas?

```
import sys
import win32com.client

from os.path import abspath


f = abspath(sys.argv[1])

visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.InvisibleApp")
doc = visio.Documents.Open(f)
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(1, '{}.pdf'.format(f), 0, 0)

visio.Quit()
exit(0)
```

Comment: Did you try recording a macro? Whenever I want to figure out how to automate an Office product, I record a macro of me manually performing the operation, and then I look at the code to figure out how the product itself did the operation in response to my user input.

Comment: Why Python and not VBA, which is built in to Visio and works "out of the box"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visio cannot do that. You cannot "convert all pages into a single HTML file". You'll have a "root" file and a folder of "supporting" files.

`VisSaveAsWeb` is pretty well documented, no need to guess: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/vissaveasweb-object-visio-save-as-web

-- update

With python, it turned out to be not that trivial to deal with SaveAsWeb. It seems to default to **a custom interface** (non-dispatch). I don't think it's possible deal with this using win32com library, but with [comtypes](https://pypi.org/project/comtypes/) seems to work (comtypes library is building the client based on the type library, i.e. it also supports "custom" interfaces):

```
import sys
import comtypes

from comtypes import client
from os.path import abspath

f = abspath(sys.argv[1])

visio = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Visio.InvisibleApp")
doc = visio.Documents.Open(f)

comtypes.client.GetModule("{}\\SAVASWEB.DLL".format(visio.Path))

saveAsWeb = visio.SaveAsWebObject.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.VisSAW.IVisSaveAsWeb)
webPageSettings = saveAsWeb.WebPageSettings.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.VisSAW.IVisWebPageSettings)

webPageSettings.TargetPath = "{}.html".format(f)
webPageSettings.QuietMode = True

saveAsWeb.AttachToVisioDoc(doc)
saveAsWeb.CreatePages()

visio.Quit()
exit(0)
```

Other than that, you can try "command line" interface:
http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2010/03/automating-visios-save-as-web-output.html

```
import sys
import win32com.client

from os.path import abspath

f = abspath(sys.argv[1])

visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.InvisibleApp")
doc = visio.Documents.Open(f)
visio.Addons("SaveAsWeb").Run("/quiet=True /target={}.htm".format(f))

visio.Quit()
exit(0)
```

Other than that you could give a try to my visio svg-export :)

Comment: In fact, Visio does that via GUI. What I want is to automate that.

Comment: Visio does NOT save html as a single file. Check your disk and you will find a folder named <your file name>_files

Comment: 1 (one) HTML file and a folder with resources related to that file. That's just what I need.

Comment: Great, but I don't know how to use it with Python.  See my code: https://pastebin.com/3THMj0e0 :)

Comment: It seems now I've got the issue - save as web is using custom interface. Therefor from python, it's not trivial to deal with that (win32com does not support custom interfaces, but you could comtypes instead - it does). I have updated the answer.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: My final work is here and the thread will be marked as solved: https://gist.github.com/forkd/9d4d12f7e86701b90757a0f16cf48c02